Hotkey to set dimensions to a specific value
Is there a hotkey to set a mesh object's dimensions on a specific axis?
The closest I have is the s scale hotkey, but it scales the object with a multiplier rather than setting the value.

Why don't you just enter the dimension in the Dimensions for the specific axis and then apply the scale? Not as quick as a hotkey, but better than having to calculate the matching scale factor to get the correct dimension...

That's what I'm doing right now, clicking on each axis and entering the dimension. I'd like to know if a hotkey is available, similar to being able to rotate by pressing r and entering the desired rotation in degrees.
